how doI separate discord.py slash commands into separate .py files?
I've got some Discord bots that are through discord.py and use slash commands; they generally follow this theme:
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *, i: discord.Intents):
        super().__init__(intents=i)
        self.tree = app_commands.CommandTree(self)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.tree.sync()


@client.tree.command(name="test", description="test")
async def test_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    #some stuff


async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.start(token)

asyncio.run(main())


All of my commands are done through this method, how I am able to separate commands into separate Python files, so I can start organising my bigger bots that have a lot of functions?
I have tried doing doing it using groups eg:
test_group = app_commands.Group(name="test_group", description="test group desc")

@test_group.command(name="new-command")
async def test_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    #some stuff

client.tree.add_command(test_group)


But I can't seem to get it working' no matter which way I make it.

A few things I want to point out for a better bot code on discord.py. Firstly use bot instead of client. Secondly it's not really necessary to inherit a class from client instance. Thirdly don't use three for usual commands. Forth that's not a good way to initiate a command group (cog). I will make an answer covering all of them and your question.

Your question is already answered by Łukasz Kwieciński here: Łukasz Kwieciński's Answer

@Brawldude2 sorry for the late reply, this would be amazingly helpful if its possible to show me examples of the points here, I have always made my bots the way i have set it up above, i would love to have a better way to do it

It won't be really related to question but here's the repo I have my templates in: MinimalisticCodeTemplates It also includes a discord.py bot you can start working on. I also recommend you to use normal bot commands instead of slash ones as they are easier to start with compared to slash command and tree commands since you have to do syncing and stuff
